# Do CNNs (Convolution Neural Networks) require a CSV file?

Tags: csv, machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, computer-vision

I am trying to do some image classification using TensorFlow, and I'm using a CNN. I have a CSV file for the images, but I was wondering if I need a CSV file when I load the dataset (images), or will the CNN do the classification by itself without one. I'm pretty new to Machine Learning and TensorFlow, so some details would be helpful.

Comment: no, you do not need csv files.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why/what you are asking, but I think the answer to your question should be: no, you do not require a CVS (did you mean CSV?) file. If you write a program that loads the data with the labels you should be fine!

Comment: I'm asking if a cnn requires a csv file with labels in order to learn, or does it learn without one.

Comment: If you are doing supervised learning you need to have labels in order to learn. Unsupervised learning learns without any labels.